# IPhone X home indicator

Tags: ios, swift, gesture, iphone-x

I was trying to figure how to work with the iPhone X notch but I can't understand how to make the home bar not activate when a user swipes from the bottom.

I used the following code as suggested in [this post](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/iphone-x-dealing-with-home-indicator-2e8e47f5647f) and it does work for the top swipe but it doesn't work for the bottom swipe.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return .all
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to prevent iPhone X users from closing your app?

Comment: **auto-hiding** of `home indicator` should be for short period only, Other wise your app may reject from appStore.

Comment: No lol I just want the user to have to double swipe to exit the app like this guy did [link](https://github.com/kharrison/CodeExamples/tree/master/Swiper/Swiper)

Answer (score 0):

This bit works perfectly. Swipe twice or "fast" to show the home bar.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        return super.prefersStatusBarHidden
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {
    return [.all]
}
```

A question i have is--Will apple allow it if and when I send it in my code when i submit my app to the app store?